# Replacing a door handle with no visible screws

Tags: doors, doorknob

I am trying to replace a door handle that doesn't have any visible screws. I am assuming the first step is to remove this faceplate that probably conceals the screws underneath, however the plate does not budge. There is a tiny divot in the plate, large enough for a screwdriver, but no amount of twisting, pulling, or prying via the divot seems to remove the faceplate (rose?). Any tips on how to remove this without causing any damage?
[image: side view with divot]
[image: handle]

Answer (score 2):

Lever-style handles like this often have a face plate that you need to remove. Your first image shows the nub on the face place. I've circled it for you

[image]

Slide a flat screwdriver into that slot and twist it. The plate will come off and expose the screws.

Comment: try pushing first .... it may unlatch the cover ... twisting may damage the cover it it is a push type latch

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you need to rotate the place to remove it. I would guess counter clockwise. But as Machavity states, it probably just pops off.